# Find kth element in an expanding string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Given a string of the form `AB2C3` and an int `k`.Expand the string as `ABABC3` then `ABABCABABCABABC`. The task is to find the *k*th element.  You have limited memory so you can not expand the entire string. You just have to find the *k*th element.

I am not sure about how to go about it. It was asked to my friend in a coding interview and I have given a lot of thought to it but I am not getting an efficient solution.

Comment: Think. How would you do it on paper? What's the 90th letter of `(A)80(BC)10(D)10`? Which is the relevant section, and which letter from that section will it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** An `O(1)` space and `O(N)` time version follows. See below.

---

Original solution uses `O(1)` space and `O(N log k)` time, where `n` is the size of the unexpanded string:

```
char find_kth_expanded(const char* s, unsigned long k) {
  /* n is the number of characters in the expanded string which we've
   * moved over.
   */
  unsigned long n = 0;
  const char *p = s;
  for (;;) {
    char ch = *p++;
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      int reps = ch - '0';
      if (n * reps <= k)
        n *= reps;
      else {
        /* Restart the loop. See below. */
        k = k % n;
        p = s;
        n = 0;
      }
    }
    else if (ch == 0 || n++ == k)
      return ch;
  }
}
```

The function simply moves left to right through the string, keeping track of how many characters in the expanded string it has passed over. If that value reaches `k`, then we've found the `k`th character in the expanded string. If a repetition would skip over character `k`, then we reduce `k` to the index within the repetition, and restart the scan.

It's obvious that it uses `O(1)` space. To prove that it runs in `O(N log k)`, we need to count the number of times that the loop is restarted. If we are restarting, then `k≥n`, because otherwise we would previously have returned the character at `n`. If `k≥2n` then `n≤k/2` so `k%n≤k/2`. If `k<2n` then `k%n = k-n`. But `n>k/2`, so `k-n<k-k/2` and therefore `k%n<k/2`.

So when we restart, the new value of `k` is at most half of the old value. So in the worst case, we'll restart `log2k` times.

---

While the above solution is easy to understand, we can actually do better. Instead of restarting the scan, we can just scan backwards once we scan past `k` (expanded) characters. During the backwards scan, we need to always correct `k` to the range in the current segment by taking its modulus base the segment length:

```
/* Unlike the above version, this one returns the point in the input
 * string corresponding to the kth expanded character.
 */
const char* find_kth_expanded(const char* s, unsigned long k) {
  unsigned long n = 0;
  while (*s && k >= n) {
    if (isdigit(*s))
      n *= *s - '0';
    else
      ++n;
    ++s;
  }
  while (k < n) {
    --s;
    if (isdigit(*s)) {
      n /= *s - '0';
      k %= n;
    }
    else
      --n;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Neither of the above functions correctly handle the case where the multiplier is 0 and `k` is less than the length of the segment multiplied by 0. If `0` is a legal multiplier, a simple solution would be to reverse scan the string for the last `0` and start find_kth_expanded at the following character. Since the reverse scan is `O(N)`, the time complexity is not changed.

Comment: A great answer. I ran it and verified that it works .

Comment: Very compact and understandable ... Great answer I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take a look at the string. Your string is composed of two parts: A data part and an information part. The data part contains the actual string to be repeated and the information part contains the actual number of repeats.

If you understand this, you already understand the pattern of the data.

Next step is to handle special cases, like negative repeat number, real repeat number instead of integers. You could actually say that repeat is the substring of your string found at the very end and defined by the rule that it can contain only digits. If you think about it this way, then you will have two cases: the string either ends with a digit, or the string does not end with a digit. In the first case, we have a valid repeat number, in the second case we have to throw an exception.

If we still have a valid repeat number, then it might have multiple digits, so, you must explore your string to find the last index which is not associated to a digit. The substring after that index is the information part, which is rp (repeat number). Also, this index is actually equal to the length of your data part - 1, let's call the length L.

If you have a valid rp, then the actual length of the result string is L * rp.

Now, if k is an int, you still have to throw exception if it is negative, also, k < L * rp is another important validation rule.

If everything is valid, then the actual value's index is calculated by:

k % L

You do not have to actually calculate the result string to determine the k'th character, because you can use the fact that you have a repeated pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a fun puzzle program to write.

Here's an answer that is written in C#. It is an exercise to convert to C++! There are 2 recursive functions, one which calculates the length of the expanded string, and another that finds the *k*th character of the given string. It works backwards, from right to left, stripping off one character at a time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace expander
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string y = "AB2C3";
            Console.WriteLine("length of expanded = {0} {1}", y, length(y));
            for(uint k=0;k<length(y);k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("found {0} = {1}",k,find(k,y));
            }
        }

        static char find(uint k, string s)
        {
            string left = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
            char   last = s[s.Length - 1];
            uint len = length(left);
            if (last >= '0' && last <= '9')
            {
                if (k > Convert.ToInt32(last -'0') * len) throw new Exception("k out of range");
                uint r = k % len;
                return find(r, left );
            }
            if (k < len) return find(k, left);
            else if (k == len) return last;
            else throw new Exception("k out of range");
        }
        static uint length(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length == 0) return 0;
            char x = s[s.Length - 1];
            uint len = length(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
            if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')
            {
                return Convert.ToUInt32(x - '0') * len;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1 + len;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample output, which shows that the `find` function replicates the expansion if you iterate over all valid values of k (0 to len-1).

```
length of expanded AB2C3 is 15
if k=0, the character is A
if k=1, the character is B
if k=2, the character is A
if k=3, the character is B
if k=4, the character is C
if k=5, the character is A
if k=6, the character is B
if k=7, the character is A
if k=8, the character is B
if k=9, the character is C
if k=10, the character is A
if k=11, the character is B
if k=12, the character is A
if k=13, the character is B
if k=14, the character is C
```

The memory usage of this program is limited to the stack usage. The stack depth will be equal to the length of the string. In this C# program, I am copying the string over and over, so that wastes memory. But even with this poor management, it should use O(N^2) memory, where N is the length of the string. The actual expanded string can be much, much longer.  For example, "AB2C999999" is only N=10, so should use O(100) memory elements, but the expanded string is over 2 million characters long.

Comment: rici's answer is much better than this one. I didn't delete mine because SO doesn't like it when answers get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In first case, string is 'AB2C3', where '2' is removed from 'AB2C3' and left side of the '2' ('AB') in string 'AB2C3' is repeated '2' times. It becomes 'ABABC3'.

In second case, string is 'ABABC3', where '3' is removed from 'ABABC3' and left side of the '3' ('ABABC') in string 'ABABC3' is repeated '3' times. It becomes 'ABABCABABCABABC'.

Algorithm would be like this:

```
1) READ ONE CHAR AT A TIME UNTIL END OF STRING
   IF CHAR IS AN INT THEN k := k - CHAR + 1
2) RETURN STRING[k]
```

Comment: k is not part of the original string. it is an independent variable.  k could be 1; the 1st character of the output is 'A'. k could be 15; the 15th character of the output is 'C'.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of 'k'? why it is given? The string is already has enough information in it.

Comment: *k* is a number between 1 and the expanded length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the point of the question was figuring out how far you will have to expand until you are able to get the `k`th element.

In this example for `0 < k <= 2` assuming the first character is index 1 you don't need to expand at all.

For `2 < k <= 5` you only need to expand the first part.

for `5 < k <= 10` you will need to expand unil `ABABCABABC` and for `10 < k <= 15` you will need to do the full expansion.

Answer (score -2):

Giving the code for this problem.

```
public String repeater(String i_string, int k){
    String temp = ""; 
    for (int i=0; i < k; ++i)
        temp = temp + i_string.substring(0,k);
    temp = temp + i_string.substring(k, i_string.length());
    return temp;
}
```

I haven't considered the limited memory issue as there hasn't any clear information mentioned on the same.

You do not need any additional memory. You could print the data to console as per user requirements. If you are just displaying, then the return type of the method could be excluded too :) You just need a temporary string, to hold processed data.

```
public void repeater2(String i_string, int k){
    String temp = i_string.substring(0,k);
    // Repeat and Print the first half as per requirements.
    for (int i=0; i < k; ++i)
        System.out.print(temp);
    // Print the second half of the string AS - IS. 
    System.out.print(i_string.substring(k, i_string.length()));
}
```

If the K value is 1, then the string will be printed once. As per requirements. We would need two iterations. 
Code will almost be same for C++ or Java, with minor changes, i hope you get the actual logic.

Comment: Why not explain the question in detail? I haven't got your above quote. The code is expected to repeat the elements prior K right?